# removing adjacent duplicate strings from an array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, duplicates

This is the text file I have written :

```
this is the first line
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the second line
this is the second line
this is the third line
this is the first line
```

I am trying to remove the adjacent duplicate strings, so the output would be:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the third line
this is the first line
```

This is what I have written so far :

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
getline(infile,arr[i]);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
        int j = i+1;
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
                for(int k = i; k<n; k++)
                arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                n--;
        }
}
```

this is the output I get:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the second line
this is the third line
this is the first line
```

How to fix this? 
P.S.: It has to be solved iteratively, which is why I'm trying to do it this way.

Comment: What is the type of `arr`?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: it is a string array. 
everything has to be solved iteratively, i cant use any pre-existing functions, or recursion.  :{ 
i am fairly new to computer science and really struggling with this problem.

Comment: by debugger do you mean compiler ? 
ive worked on it for a while now, i thought i could really use some help.

Comment: Your problem happens when you need to deduplicate the string more than 2 times, so in your case it happened because "second line" is repeated 3 times. Try to trace your code by hand on a piece of paper and see why it's not working correctly.

Comment: @Stardust1992 _"by debugger do you mean compiler ?"_ No.

Comment: The problem is simpler than you think. You don't need any arrays or extra loops. Just keep a variable with the last line you read. When you read each line, compare it with that variable. If it is the same, ignore the line, otherwise print the line and set the variable to that new value. Do you understand how this would solve the problem?

Comment: Regarding the debugger, I am all for learning how to use a debugger - and learning what a debugger is! But in this case I think the code isn't ready for a debugger. First some thought should be put into the problem and how it could be solved in a very simple manner (not with arrays and nested loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem happens when you have more than 2 duplicates of the same line. In your case, this causes the problem.

```
this is the second line
this is the second line
this is the second line
```

The issue is that you only de-duplicate the line once with the next element.

Example:
If you have 4 lines in which lines 1, 2, 3 are duplicates, you would:

1. Compare 1 with 2, and then remove 2, compressing the array to 1, 3
2. Instead of comparing 1 with 3, you would skip to compare 3 with 4 (wrong)

In order to fix your solution, you need to make sure you don't increment `i` until it doesn't match the next element `i+1`.

```
i = 0;
while (i < n)
{
    int j = i+1;
    if(arr[i] == arr[j])
    {
        for(int k = i; k<n; k++)
        {
            arr[k] = arr[k+1];
        }
        n--;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

```
auto end = std::unique(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned, i cant use this. i have to do it iteratively. which is why im trying to it this way, i cant use recursion either.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < count(original_array); i++)
{
    if(i == 0) // check for first entry
    {
        new_array[] = original_array[i];
        temp = original_array[i];
    }
    if(temp != original_array[i]) // check thereafter
    {
        new_array[] = original_array[i];
        temp = original_array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `new_array[] = original_array[i];` This won't compile at all.

Comment: Hii Friend,in that line, i just wanted to tell that, put the old value to new array.... the code is not written for any particular language... it's just a Logic...